# Publish custom application on android market

Tags: android, google-play

I develop intranet applications for my customer and I'd like to deploy them.

I can install applications without android market http://maketecheasier.com/install-applications-without-the-market/2011/01/28 but I'd like to benefits of the upgrade utility without make it public.

Is it possible ? Or is there a method to deploy the update on 5-10 terminal ?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no official Android Market support for this, but there are APIs and 3rd party solutions, take a look at the answers to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217525/distributing-and-updating-an-enterprise-android-application-that-is-to-be-used).

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to release your App to the Android market as "Private".  You can limit by country, carrier, device, and a bunch of other parameters - which sometimes can be used to limit your audience enough.

Bottom line - you cannot release private to the Android Market.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at https://www.push-link.com/ . It does the job in amazing fashion...

Comment: well it looks very interesting but it's sad that there tool cannot be installed on our server. If that server is compromised, all terminal can be also :(

Comment: Many of internet services can provide more uptime and reliability than intranet data centers... Unfortunately this is the nature of the internet services... trust or quit... :)