# I have an admin app for iOS and Android that I want to distribute to clients and businesses. What is the best way to make this happen?

Tags: android, ios, iphone

As the title says, I have an administration mobile app for both iOS and Android and I want to be able to distribute it to all of our clients and businesses, but I don't want to have it publicly available on the app stores.  Is it possible to put an app on the app store that's only accessible if we give them the direct link?  Or is it possible to distribute the app easily bypassing the app stores?  Or is there a service that I can use to deploy to certain devices and also be able to alert them when an update happens?  There is also a public app in the app store already, but the app I'm referring to is for administration of the data alone and that's why we don't want it public.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On the iOS side of things, you'll want to sign up for an Enterprise developer account. You can learn more here: https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/

On the android side of things, this SO answer seems to give you enough details to get started: [Distributing (and updating) an enterprise Android application that is to be used in-house only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217525/distributing-and-updating-an-enterprise-android-application-that-is-to-be-used)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a login system for your clients in your android/ios app.